# rails split and capitalize words in [ ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split, delimiter, capitalize

I am trying to capitalize words with a format like this:

`america [asia] europe`

and I want to make it look like this:

`America [Asia] Europe`

What regex should I put in the .split option?

Comment: Your data doesn't make sense. What is `america [asia] europe`? An array, a string?

Comment: Obligatory joke: You have a problem. You decide to use a regex. Now you have two problems.  Seriously: is that the only form of the string, or can the brackets move around, like "[america] asia europe", "america [asia] europe", or "america asia [europe]"? I'd try stuff out in an online regex tester.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is `america [asia] europe`, then there is no need for `regex`. Instead use, the builtin helpers methods within Rails. The method `titleize` is meant for this kind of thing.

```
➜  test_app git:(master) ✗ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)

test_app :001 > t = 'america [asia] europe'
 => "america [asia] europe" 

test_app :002 > t.titleize
 => "America [Asia] Europe"
```